# Derive $ \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{1} f(xt) dt$

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing some calculus in preparation for multi-variables, finding this: 
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{1} f(xt) dt$$
Please don't derive it for me, but apparently I'm more rusty than I should be because I don't know where to begin. Could I get a hint or pointer in the right direction?

For instance, what happens to the interval if we bring the constant multiplier into the integral? I thought nothing at first, but then how is the interval change related to getting x inside of the function? This is fundamental fact stuff that I need to review again, so pointers on where to look for help would suffice as well.

Comment: Hint: let $u =\ldots$

Comment: Usa a substitution: what would you try to make the LHS integral look like the RHS one? BTW, why did you tag this "algebra-precalculus"? That's obviously wrong.

Comment: Enforce a substitution.

Comment: @NickD tagged as algebra-precalculus because I wasn't thinking about using a substitution, so I thought I was forgetting something trivial about functions. I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in both integrals, the value inside the brackets runs through 0 to x. Therefore, it suggests you to do something to make the expression inside the brackets the same, which means letting $u=\dots$

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*: Write LHS=$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xf(u)du$ and then substitute $u=xt$.